# In react/rails app, after i make a post request i receive errors like 500 or 422

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, axios, crud

The same controller code works when i make a request from frontend of ruby on rails, but when i make a post request from react it ends up in error.

Edit: The goal is to upload a file and store it in public folder so that it could be displayed later.

The code for react is as follows:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setGame({ ...game, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

const handleFile = (e) => {
    setGame({ ...game, file: e.target.files[0] })
}

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    const formData = new FormData()
    for (var key in game) {
        formData.append(`${key}`, game[key]);
        console.log(`${key}` + ": " + game[key])
    }

    axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api/v1/projects`, formData)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

The code for controller is as follows:

```
module Api
module V1
    class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
        protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
        skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
        
        before_action :set_project, only: %i[ show iframe edit update destroy ]
        current_user = User.first

        def index
            @projects = Project.all
            render json: @projects
        end

        # GET /projects/new
        def new
            @project = Project.new
        end

        def iframe
            @html_content = @project.files.blobs.find_by(content_type: 'text/html')&.download
            render layout: false # To render the iframe view without the default layout
        end

        def create
            @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
            respond_to do |format|
            if @project.save
                # Create the image folder and move image files
                add_files_to_image_folder(@project) # Call the method here

                format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "Project was successfully created." }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
            else
                format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
            end
        end

        def show
            @project = Project.find(params[:id])
            render json: @project
        end

        # GET /projects/1/edit
        def edit
        end

        def update
            respond_to do |format|
            if @project.update(project_params)
                # Call the method to add image files to the folder
                add_files_to_image_folder(@project)

                format.html { redirect_to project_url(@project), notice: "Project was successfully updated." }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
            else
                format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
            end
        end

        def destroy
            @project = Project.find(params[:id])
            @project.destroy
        end

        private
        

        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_project
            if Project.exists?(params[:id])
                @project = Project.find(params[:id])
            else
                redirect_to projects_path, alert: 'Uh oh looks like the game u wanted to play MAGICALLY DISPAPPEARED :00'
            end
        end
        

        # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
        def project_params
            params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, files: [])
        end


        def add_files_to_image_folder(project)
            base_folder_path = Rails.root.join('public/uploads', project.folder_name)
            FileUtils.mkdir_p(base_folder_path)
            
            project.files.each do |file|
                # Check the content type of the file
                case file.content_type
                    when 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'text/css', 'text/javascript', 'application/javascript'
                        # Save the file to the main folder
                        file_path = File.join(base_folder_path, file.filename.to_s)
                    
                        # Save the file to the respective folder
                        File.open(file_path, 'wb') { |f| f.write(file.download) }
                    else
                        # Skip files with unknown content types or handle them accordingly
                    next
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end

Rest of the CRUD operations are working fine, expect edit, it is partially working i am able to edit title and description but the file part of edit is also now working.
Kindly help me resolve this issue

The rails log:
Started POST "/api/v1/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-10-24 20:04:14 +0500
Processing by Api::V1::ProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"title"=>"new tic tac toe", "description"=>"description of tic tac toe", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f003cda5690 @tempfile=#Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20231024-13148-nlwpw6.erb, @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="tictactoe.html.erb", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="tictactoe.html.erb"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 569)

NoMethodError (undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:35:in `create'

Updated Logs:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: project):
```

app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:89:in `project_params' app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:30:in` create'
Started POST "/api/v1/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-10-26 17:18:05 +0500
Processing by Api::V1::ProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"title"=>"new temp title", "description"=>"new temp description", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fbbda156c90 @tempfile=#Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20231026-3448-amq41q.erb, @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="tictactoe.html.erb", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="tictactoe.html.erb"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:11:in `set_user'
Completed 400 Bad Request in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 7.7ms | Allocations: 1240)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: project):

app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:89:in `project_params' app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:30:in` create'

Updated Log:
Started POST "/api/v1/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-10-26 18:27:34 +0500
Processing by Api::V1::ProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"title"=>"new title ", "description"=>"new description", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fbbbb0437f0 @tempfile=#Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20231026-3448-9efnt8.erb, @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="tictactoe.html.erb", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="tictactoe.html.erb"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 447)

NoMethodError (undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:31:in `create'

Comment: Could you post the Rails-Logs of the incoming requests? Maybe you can compare these logs from the local and from the react-environment. Do you find any "unpermitteld attributes" entries within your logs?

Comment: Do you really need/want to reinvent the file uploads wheel? [ActiveStorage provides the both the server and client side components](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) for handling uploads.

Comment: If you do want to reinvent the wheel you have a lot of work to do. You need to send a `multipart/formdata` request and the files must be added as separate parts to the request. You also need to provide a token for the CSRF protection. What I don't understand when looking at this code is that it looks like you're using ActiveStorage but there is all this weird kludge code in add_files_to_image_folder that you don't need.

Comment: @zaphodbln_ i have added the data coming to rails and i think you were referring to this when you said rails logs

Comment: Can you check what `current_user` is? It looks like it might be nil, so I would just make sure that the user is signed in in the controller method or else make it an authenticated user only route.

Comment: @ztcollazo current_user is defined above and i didnt include it in the code, but its declaration was /@current_user = User.first

Comment: @max can you provide me a link or running code for reference ?

Comment: I already provided you you the official guide. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html.

Comment: so it should be  @current_user.projects.new(project_params), right? But be sure to have the statement  @current_user = User.first executed - perhaps you want to share your whole controller?

Comment: @ztcollazo here you go, i have edited and shared the whole controller code

Answer (score 0):

As we see from the error message, the problem is this line:

```
@project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
```

As the message implies, current_user is null. You use it as a **local variable**, which is not available in the method.

A proper solution is to make it an **instance variable** and set this in a before action. For example you could do:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
        protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
        skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
     
        before_action: set_user  
        before_action :set_project, only: %i[ show iframe edit update destroy ]
...

        def set_user
          @current_user = User.first  # notice the leading @
        end
```

Change

```
@project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
```

to

```
@project = @current_user.projects.new(project_params)
```

and you could proceed.

---

Having solved the initial 500-error, let's tackle the ActionController::ParameterMissing error. You have to change the posted data as laid out in my latest comment. Change

```
const formData = new FormData()
for (var key in game) {
    formData.append(`${key}`, game[key]);
    console.log(`${key}` + ": " + game[key])
}
```

to something like this:

```
const formData = new FormData()  
let project_parameters = {}
for (var key in game) {
  project_parameters[key] = game[key]
  console.log(`${key}` + ": " + game[key])
}
formData.append(`project`, project_parameters)     // <<- wrap it all up in the project-param
```

Comment: zaphodbln_, i dont know why the "@" is not working, but i have tried what you suggested but now it ends up in error: 400 (Bad Request). Can you take a look at the rails log and confirm if i am getting the correct format of file

Comment: Are you talking about the logs in your question? It's not enough to add the @, you also have to make sure that @current_user is set - that's why I added the second before_action tag (please not the first code block in my answer)

Otherwise you would have to post the freshly generated logs with (possibly) another error message.

Comment: i have tried that too, but still it ends up in error 400 Bad Request, and yes i was refering to the logs in the question

Comment: At least the lines "NoMethodError (undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:35:in `create'" should have gone - so there should be different logs....

Comment: Another observation - unrelated to the aforementioned error message - your uploaded file won't be stored:


Logs:
@content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="tictactoe.html.erb"

Condition:
 when 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'text/css', 'text/javascript', 'application/javascript'

so you might want to try a different file type as well

Comment: i have added the latest logs as well

Comment: Yes - and we are progressing :)

As you can see in the error message, the project-param is missing. The standard Rails-Forms wrap all parameter into the basic entity. You can compare the incoming parameters, when you are your forms.

Put a "puts params" into your create-method and discover the difference between submitting the form and submitting from react.


The easiest way is to analyse the html-output of your rails form and apply exactly the same parameter names to your react-app

Comment: updated the latest logs, fixed the params problem

Comment: Now it's the same problem as in the beginning. Please have a look at the error message, identify the line and take it from  there.